# query that select distinct elements

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I want to print the name of all companies that have done at least 3 sponsorizations on different cities

ps: kid is primary key of company

This is what I tied so far but this return all companies that has at least 3 sponsorizations but not filter about different cities.

```
company(kid, name)
sponsorization(kid, city, sum_of_sponsorization)


SELECT c.name, count(c.name)
FROM COMPANY c
INNER JOIN SPONSORIZATION s
 ON c.kid = s.kid
GROUP BY 
c.name
having count(c.name) > 3
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. And also take a look at [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can try below- with count(distinct s.city)

```
SELECT c.name
FROM COMPANY c
INNER JOIN SPONSORIZATION s ON c.kid = s.kid
GROUP BY 
c.name
having count(distinct s.city) > 3
```

Answer (score 0):

count distinct  city

```
SELECT c.name
FROM COMPANY c
INNER JOIN SPONSORIZATION s
 ON c.kid = s.kid
GROUP BY 
c.name
having count(distinct s.city) > 3
```